# Java console explorer RPG game

Tags: java, console

This is more of a general question not a specific coding one, but in school we got this assignment to make our own dungeon RPG console explorer game you know the one with tons of text where you type where to go, etc. My question here to the more experienced programmers is what would be the best way to fundamentally approach this like read the text from a file and store the play options into an array, etc. I am open to having to learn anything new. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objected Oriented programming is Java's forte. If you are going with Java, try to take advantage of these primitives.

For example, reading everything from a file and having a user select inputs with his keyboard would be something more akin to scripting, which you could perfectly do with something like Python and would therefore be a situation of using a rocket launcher to kill a mouse.

The array thing, not sure what you mean, but generally storing such information statically in an array is generally not a good idea, especially if the information is already stored in files (unless you're going to be using them all of the time).